# Put yourself automatically in cc with mutt

Tags: email, mutt

How can I configure `.muttrc` such that when I send an email, by default I put myself in C.C.?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`my_hdr`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#my_hdr) for that:

```
my_hdr Cc: <my@email>
```

If you only want this to save your emails, you can also use [`record`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#record):

> This specifies the file into which your outgoing messages should be
>   appended. (This is meant as the primary method for saving a copy of
>   your messages, but another way to do this is using the `` my_hdr''
>   command to create a Bcc: field with your email address in it.)